How to use the vector arrow from txfonts in Cambria Math
Here is the code I used
\documentclass[12pt,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,txfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}
\[ \overrightarrow{AB} \]
\[ \overrightarrow{a} \]
\end{document}

This is the result: 

I want the big vector arrow like this: 
\documentclass[12pt,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,txfonts}
\begin{document}
\[ \overrightarrow{AB} \]
\[ \overrightarrow{a} \]
\end{document}



Is there a way to do this?

amsfonts amssymb and txfonts are all 8 bit legacy encoded fonts that do not fit unicode-math. txfonts are based on the Tex gyre Termes OpenMath font so you could use that for the arrows most likely, also unicode-math includes amsmath so you do not need to list that.
